# passing classes within classes c++

Tags: c++, class

I have this mouse and maze program where I have defined a separate class for the mouse and the maze. I have included in the header of each class the other classes header file. In the mouse one, if I pass by reference the maze (so function(maze& myMaze, mouse& myMouse) it checks out fine. If I do the same in the maze, it says is not a type of that class. How do I fix this?

from maze cpp:

```
void maze::initialize_map(mouse& myMouse) {} (error of previous mention)
```

from mouse cpp:

```
string mouse::get_movement(maze& myMaze, mouse& myMouse) {} (no error)
```

mouse header:

```
#ifndef MOUSE_H
#define MOUSE_H
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "maze.h"

class mouse {
private:
    int life, locationX, locationY, toLocX, toLocY, los_max_distance;
    char los_direction;
    bool sight;

public:
    mouse(): life(50), locationX(0), locationY(0), toLocX(0), toLocY(0), los_max_distance(0), los_direction('0'), sight(false) {}

    int get_life() const;
    int get_locationX() const;
    int get_locationY() const;
    bool get_sight() const;
    std::string get_movement(maze&, mouse&);

    void set_life(int);
    void set_location(int, int, maze&);
    void set_sight();
    void unset_sight();
    void set_path(char);
    void set_distance(char);
};

#endif  /* MOUSE_H */
```

maze header:

```
#ifndef MAZE_H
#define MAZE_H
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stack>
#include "mouse.h"

class maze {
private:
    static const int MAX_LENGTH = 20;
    static const int MAX_WIDTH = 20;
    char board[MAX_LENGTH][MAX_WIDTH];
    char wall, open, mouse, cheese;
    int lastIntersectionX, lastIntersectionY, locationMX, locationMY, locationCX, locationCY, last_room;
    bool scent;
    std::stack <int> lastDirection;
    struct directions {
        std::string direction[4], next, prev;
        int longest, length[4];
    } movement;

public:
    maze(): wall('+'), open('.'), mouse('m'), cheese('c'), lastIntersectionX(0), lastIntersectionY(0), locationMX(0), locationMY(0), locationCX(0), locationCY(0), last_room(0), scent(false) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 20; ++k) {
                board[i][k] = '0';
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            movement.direction[i] = "none";
            movement.length[i] = 0;
        }

        movement.next = "none", movement.prev = "none", movement.longest = 0;
    };

    void initialize_map(mouse&);

    void view_map() const;
    char get_map_room(char, char) const;
    void set_map_room(int, int, char);
    void line_of_sight(maze&, mouse&);
    void get_exit(maze&, mouse&);
    std::string get_next(maze&, mouse&) const;
    std::string get_prev(maze&, mouse&) const;
    int get_longest() const;

    int get_mouse_locationX() const;
    int get_mouse_locationY() const;
    void view_location() const;
    void set_mouse_location(int, int);
    void set_cheese_location(int, int);
};

#endif  /* MAZE_H */
```

NOTE: This is a lab for my class. However, this particular problem has nothing to do with it. THe professor tells me I'm making this harder than I have to, and I likely am, but I am enjoying doing this work in this way and I'd like to continue. If I can get these two to pass information I can move forward with my project.

Comment: Why not make movement an enum instead of a string?

Comment: You don't include the exact error message.

Comment: I'm not seeing where you call that method. You should also make sure to show the exact error message.

Comment: You have a circular reference. Try forward-declaring mouse in maze's header.

Comment: The exact error message appears when I hover over any mouse& reference in the prototype functions:
    

    'code'char maze::mouse

Comment: Copy and paste the error message from your build output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular dependency; each header tries to include the other. The result is that one class definition will be included before the other, and won't know about the other class, hence the error.

In your case, `mouse` doesn't need the full definition of `maze`, only that the class exists. So remove the inclusion of the definition

```
#include "maze.h"
```

and instead just declare the class

```
class maze;
```

I think you can do the same in the other header.

Comment: +1 ... and if you can you should, on general principles, to reduce coupling. (Include everything needed to compile a header in the header, and not a bit more.)

Comment: I have tried this, and the one below. In the mouse header, it recognizes both maze as a class of its own and mouse as a class of its own. In maze header, it is trying to recognize mouse as maze::mouse class.

Comment: @Greg: Yes, you've given the same name to two different things, so within the class the member name hides the class name. You could rename the variable, or you could refer to the class as `::mouse` (i.e. the thing called `mouse` in the global namespace) to disambiguate.

Comment: I get it. Okay.  It was because they were linked and that the names were the same that duplication arose. Well, thank you. It's now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do one or more of:

- Use forward declaration of one the class. For example `class maze;` in `mouse.h` header before `mouse` class, OR the other way around.
- `#include` required headers in CPP/H files. For example `#include"maze.h"` in `mouse.cpp`